# VS Code: persistent vim-mode undo/redo that outlives tab closure

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, if I edit a file, then close the tab, then open it again, I want to be able to press `u` in vim mode to undo the previous changes. It works with cmd-Z, which should be the exact same behavior as vim-mode `u`, but it's not. How do I fix this?

Comment: Is the setting `Files: Restore Undo Stack` enabled (which is the default)?  If not, enable it.  What you want works for me with that setting enabled.  If that doesn't help, what kind of file is it not working in - or does it not work in all file types?

Comment: Ah, thanks for getting me to look into this more. I've updated my question: it turns out this is only a problem with vim-mode `u`. cmd-Z works, but `u`—which should be the exact same!—does not. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: I don't use vim so sorry, no help from me there.